# Is it ok to use same wallet on multiple devices

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Would it be ok to use the same offline wallet, i.e generated from same mnemonic seed, on multiple devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly fine. The only thing to note is that certain information is stored in your local wallet file that will only be available to the device which has access to that wallet file.

In particular, your address book, the "tx keys" which allow you to prove payment, records of the Monero wallet addresses you've sent payment to and the notes you may have written as descriptions of each transaction you've made. These will only be available to the device with the specific wallet file from which those address book entries were created or those transactions were sent. For this reason some people will want to back up their wallet file on each device.

The most important thing is that you will always be able to see your entire balance and have full access to all of your funds from any device, even if you lose all wallet files and have to restore your wallet from seed.